# android PagerTitleStrip how to modify it to show all pages

Tags: java, android

Is there any chance to modify PagerTitleStrip to show all pages, not only three. Basing on that what I found probably no. But could you propose any alternative with similar role?

Comment: What do you mean by only 3? You can display a custom title for all the pages with the position. What did you try?

Comment: PagerTitleStrip shows by default only three pages name: previous, current, next. While I would like to display the names of all pages (fragments) (some kind of more rich navigation info, ex. if I have 8 pages, the names of all 8 pages are displayed on the top and one is marked with some color pointing the current page).

Comment: Please post the FragmentPagerAdapter you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SELECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.general).toUpperCase();  \\GET YOUR STRING
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.Home).toUpperCase(); \\GET YOUR STRING
        case 2:
                return getString(R.string.something).toUpperCase();\\GET YOUR STRING
        case 3:
                return getString(R.string.another).toUpperCase(); \\  DO the SAME IF YOU HAVE MORE STRING
        }
        return null;
    }

}


    public static class DummySectionFragment extends ListFragment{

            public static final String ARG_SELECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment(){

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        p = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SELECTION_NUMBER);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewrow, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help but the code you presented is the classical ViewPager code. Mine works witout problems as well. But simply I need a different component - the one which will show the position not within the prev, curr, next items only but the one which will show the position among all pages. ex. "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8", where the current page ex. "4" is marked with red.